# How to avoid session-related parameters in business layer?

Tags: ejb, parameter-passing, multi-tier

I have a Java EE application (simple web GUI, a large EJB 3 business layer, JPA) whose most functions depend on the currently logged-on user.

Because of this, the EJBs are infested with omnipresent `String userName` parameter. You can hardly find a non-trivial method that goes without it, and it descends all the way down to the most basic EJBs. Occasionally it is supplemented by other session-related parameters, like user's locale.

As a result, parameter lists grow and code clarity suffers. It's probably a common problem, how to avoid it? Pushing more code to the GUI client seems even crazier idea.

Comment: Have a session-scoped user bean.

Comment: Its better to have a entity with all the attributes related to user & can pass this entity to other layers, instead of passing individual attributes - resulting in growing parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE has support for security context propogation across various layers. For e.g. checkout various methods on the EJBContext related to authentication/authorization such as `getCallerPrincipal()`, `isCallerInRole()`. I suggest you read the below two articles

1. [High level introduction to end to end security](http://ejbvn.wordpress.com/category/week-3-advanced-ejb-applications/day-19-understanding-security/)
2. [Introduction to Security in the Java EE Platform](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbwj.html)

Comment: That's not quite the reason - we don't use this user name for application-based authorization. It's used as a key to obtain user-specific settings/preferences.

Comment: But it does concern the loggedin user, doesn't it? As such the propagated security context would be the first thing to look at. Other data could be rquested by the EJB on demand given this user name,

Comment: It's not an option for me - our application uses different authorization methods which have nothing in common with container-managed EJB security. We have no EJB roles/users defined. Currently, user name is just a HTTP session parameter.